# Analyze a complicated double summation

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued twice continuously differentiable function, and considered the below double sum $$F(t,f(x)):=\dfrac{1}{t}\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}f(x+(k-m)/\sqrt{n})\dfrac{t^{k+m}}{2^{k+m}k!m!}e^{-t}-f(x)\Big).$$ I want to compute the limit of $F(t,f(x))$ when $t\rightarrow 0$, but I don't even know how to start....

My idea was to write this double sum into two parts, the first part may be our desired answer and the second part may be zero when $t\rightarrow 0$, but I don't know what to do to analyze such a complicated sum...

Any idea?

Comment: Is $n$ on your formula a typo? or, otherwise, who''s that?

Comment: Is $n$ a constant here? If yes, then what is the problem? The term $k = m = 0$ cancels out, the others converge to $0$ if $k+m>1$, and are constants when $k+m=1$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki yes, $n$ is constant here. Would you to give a proof?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov let us treat $n$ to be a constant. after I compute the limit of $F(t,f(x))$ when $t\rightarrow 0$, I will then take $n$ to $\infty$, so now it is fixed.

Comment: why would $F$  even be well defined?

Comment: @jcdornano why not? t here is not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(t,f(x))=\dfrac{1}{t}\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}f(x+(k-m)/\sqrt{n})\dfrac{t^{k+m}}{2^{k+m}k!m!}e^{-t}-f(x)\Big)$$
only the terms $k=0,m=0$, $k=0,m=1$, $k=1,m=0$ survive in the limit $t\rightarrow 0$, the other terms vanishing at least linearly in $t$,
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}F(t,f(x))=-f(x)+\tfrac{1}{2}f(x+1/\sqrt n)+\tfrac{1}{2}f(x-1/\sqrt n),$$
where I used that
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{-t}-1}{t}=-1.$$

Comment: could you be more specific about why only these three terms survive?

Comment: assuming that the sum converges, the terms with $n+m>1$ vanish at least linearly in $t$

Comment: oh. okay. Thank you! so after this when I take $n\rightarrow\infty$, the limit is $0$?

Comment: yes it is indeed, it vanishes as $1/n$.

Comment: Okay Thank you!

Comment: sorry for one more question.. what happen if in the sum it is not $e^{-t}$ but $e^{-1}$, what will be the final limit?

Comment: then the limit diverges.

Comment: If you take the limit t to 0 before taking the limit n to infinity that replacement should not make a difference.